# Is this matrix regular?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is more a part of an exercise and not the exercise itself (which I more or less solved) but how can I quickly see that the matrix

$$A^{i} = \biggl(\biggl(\frac{1}{n^i}\biggr)\biggr)^{N}_{n=1}$$

with $N \in \mathbb{N}$ is regular, i.e. its columns $A^{i}$ are linearly independent? I use that in my proof but somehow I am missing an appropriate explanation for this particular point. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is this notation? Please use [LaTeX table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) to write out an example.

Comment: Yes. Hint: Vandermonde matrix

Comment: $A^{i}$ is the i-th colum in my matrix $A$, so the column $A^{i}$ looks like that $A^{i} = (1, \frac{1}{2^i},  \dots, \frac{1}{n^i})$ (sorry for representing my column as a row; I did that for reasons of simplicity)

Comment: @Basics Ah! Thank you, I didn't see that. And since all entries are different, we have a determinant unequal to zero which is why we have full rank which is why the matrix is regular.